# DHCP packets not sent on some interface

Tags: debian, networking

I have 2 dual interface NICs in my computer however I can't get a connection on one of them (both interfaces on the same NIC).

```
Working:
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

Not working:
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

They're both the same model so that rules out a driver issue.

In wireshark I see it's attempting to send DHCP Discover packets however if I capture what's actually sent out most packets aren't actually sent but weirdly enough one packet something makes it through (on average one every 15 minutes) but the Client MAC Address field of BOOTP is all 0.

I'm running Debian Stretch (Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux). Network is managed by NetworkManager but I tried to manually configuring those 2 interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces. I have UFW and I tried disabling it.

Comment: What MAC addresses does `ip addr`/`ifconfig` return for the Ethernet card that's not working? What results do you get if you manually set the IP address and ping to/from it? @telcoM is probably right that the card isn't working, but there is a (very unlikely) chance that the card's MAC address is either not set or is a duplicate.

Comment: They do have MAC addresses set and they are only 6 hosts on that VLAN so a conflict isn't very likely but I'll double check anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you did the `wireshark`ing using some other system, monitoring the actual output of the suspect NIC, then the symptoms you're seeing would make me seriously consider the possibility that the NIC might have a hardware fault. Is it under warranty?

Comment: Probably not, we've had it for a long time however I hadn't been used before I installed it in my computer. Good point though, I'll try in in a different computer tomorrow to verify.

Comment: So I've tried the card in another computer and it works fine. And I've verified that the problem is happening still. I wonder if it could be caused by the PCI-E slot, I don't have a free one that I can try but I'll try to swap it with the other one.